# cant set Gutters to 0 in .container-fluid bootstap 5.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

Hello i read all of answers about my question  not my answer there
i have this  Html with bottstap 5.2 :

```
<section id="title">

     <div class="container-fluid">

       <!-- Nav Bar -->

       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
           <a class="navbar-brand">Lindog</a>
           <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact </a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </nav>


       <!-- Title -->



       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
           <button type="button">Download</button>
           <button type="button">Download</button>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </section>
```

i want to have padding around .container-fluid top 5% left and right 15% and bottom 5%
i write this in css :

```
.container-fluid{
  padding: 5% 15%;
}
```

its dosent work when i inpect my site in chrome i see this section up on my css code :

```
container, .container-fluid, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

how can i remove this two part :

```
        padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
        padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
```

i try to use mx-0 in row and dosent work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **"g-0"** class with container-fluid